QuickSort Linked List in C
I need to use the Quicksort sorting algorithm to sort elements of a linked list. It is important to note that I must not just swap the key values, but the elements themselves. My code simply does not work; I believe I am making a mistake with the recursion. I would like a solution.
I created the following functions to achieve my goal:
///ELEMENTO TEM DUAS CHAVES E SEU PRÓXIMO (ENCADEAMENTO SIMPLES)///

struct elemento {
    int chave[2];
    struct elemento *prox;
};

///MOSTRAR A LISTA GERADA///

void mostrar_chaves(struct elemento *lista){

    int i;
    struct elemento *aux;
    aux = lista;
    printf("\n\n\n");

    while(lista){
       printf("%d - ", lista->chave[0]);
       lista = lista->prox;
    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

    while(aux){
       printf("%d - ", aux->chave[1]);
       aux = aux->prox;
    }

}

///QUICK SORT///

struct elemento *particiona(struct elemento *ini, struct elemento *fim){

    struct elemento *pivo, *aux, *t1, *t2, *t3, *teste;
    t1 = ini;
    t2 = ini;
    teste = ini;

    int flag = 0;

    /*printf("\nini = %d\n", ini->chave[0]);
    printf("\nfim = %d\n", fim->chave[0]);*/

    for(pivo = aux = ini; aux && aux != fim; ) {

        if(aux->chave[0] < fim->chave[0]){

            if(ini != aux){
                pivo = aux;
                flag = 1;

                if(t1 == ini){
                    if(t1 != t2){
                        teste = aux;
                        ini = ini->prox;
                        t1->prox = aux->prox;
                        aux->prox = ini;
                        t2->prox = t1;

                        t1 = aux;
                        aux = t2->prox->prox;
                    }
                    else if(t1 == t2){

                        teste = aux;
                        aux = aux->prox;
                        t1 = t1->prox;
                        t1->prox = ini;
                        ini->prox = aux;
                    }
                }

                else{

                    t1->prox = aux; //10 liga no 5
                    aux = aux->prox; //aux 20
                    t1->prox->prox = ini->prox; //5 liga no 40
                    t2->prox = ini; //10 liga no 50
                    ini = ini->prox; //ini 40
                    t2->prox->prox = aux;
                }
            }

            else{
                ini = ini->prox;
            }
        }


        if(flag == 0)
            aux = aux->prox;
        if(t1 != ini && t1->prox != ini){
            t1 = t1->prox;
        }
        if(t2 != aux && t2->prox != aux)
            t2 = t2->prox;

        flag = 0;
    }

    t1->prox = fim; //50 liga no 20
    t3 = fim->prox; //NULL
    t1->prox->prox = ini->prox; //5 liga no 40
    t2->prox = ini; //10 liga no 50
    ini->prox = t3;

    fim = ini;
    ini = aux;

    printf("\npivo = %d\n", pivo->chave[0]);*/
    mostrar_chaves(teste);

    return pivo;
}

void quick_sort(struct elemento *ini, struct elemento *fim){

    struct elemento *pivo;
    printf("\nINI_Q - %d   FIM_Q - %d\n",ini->chave[0], fim->chave[0]);
    if (ini == fim) {
        printf("\nreturn estado anterior\n");
        return;
    }
    pivo = particiona(ini, fim);

    if (pivo && pivo->prox) {
        quick_sort(pivo->prox, fim);
    }

    if (pivo && ini != pivo) {
        quick_sort(ini, pivo);
    }
}

struct elemento *fim(struct elemento *ini){
    struct elemento *fim;

    for(fim = ini; fim && fim->prox; fim = fim->prox);

    return fim;
}

void main(){
setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    struct elemento *lista_um, *lista_dois;

    lista_um = NULL;

    lista_um = (struct elemento *) malloc(sizeof(struct elemento)*6);

    lista_dois = lista_um;
    lista_dois->chave[0] = 30;
    lista_dois = lista_dois->prox;
    lista_dois->chave[0] = 50;
    lista_dois = lista_dois->prox;
    lista_dois->chave[0] = 40;
    lista_dois = lista_dois->prox;
    lista_dois->chave[0] = 10;
    lista_dois = lista_dois->prox;
    lista_dois->chave[0] = 5;
    lista_dois = lista_dois->prox;
    lista_dois->chave[0] = 20;

I am sorting the elements by the "chave[0]". At the end of the code, with the input of 6 elements in the order: 30, 50, 40, 10, 5, 20, I need them to be in the order 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  More urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example
— the same idea by a different name).  We are missing the code that defines the structure you're using and the code that creates the list.  Plus sample data, the result you're getting and the result you're expecting.

Note that QuickSort does not mesh well with linked lists.  It really wants random access to the data, but a linked list forces sequential access.  You would normally create an array from the data, sort the array, and then recreate the linked list from the sorted array.

I really know it's not usual, but I need to do it anyway. It's a training exercise.
@JonathanLeffler

Merge sort is a far better choice when you have linked lists. It also has better worst-case time complexity even when not using linked lists. Anyway, for your "training exercise", what you really should do is encapsulate your list operations in their own functions. Don't operate directly on the list structure as part of your partitioning function.

As there is a mismatch between the container and the algorithm, what is the purpose of the training?

Homework always seems to have the dumbest least realistic constraints. Though if you pick one of the first few elements as the pivot (itself a bad idea; triggers worst case performance on an already sorted list), quicksort is easy to implement on lists. The Haskell version is like three lines for example.

(I would work directly with the list structure when partitioning)

mergesort is perfect for linked lists, particularly if the list struct has a count. It can operate recursively on the linked lists directly without needing to create a flat array of indirect pointers. Otherwise, create an indirect list of pointers and qsort that: struct elemento *flat_list[100]; int idx = 0; for (struct elemento *cur = lista; cur != NULL; cur = cur->prox, ++idx) flat_list[idx] = cur; After sorting the indirect list, use it to produce a new/output linked list. BTW, what pivot point are you using?

Some comments on your code:

You assume that after partitioning, the node that was first would still be the first node in the left partition, and that the node that was last would still be the last node in the right partition, but this cannot be guaranteed. So when the partitioning is done you need more information: which are the first and last node in the left partition and which are the first and last node in the right partition.

A similar comment applies to quick_sort: it receives the linked list (first/last), but the caller will not know what the first and last nodes are after the sort has completed -- recall that function arguments are passed by value, so the caller will not know any better than that the first node would still be the first node. They have no other clue.

I didn't try to understand what t1, t2, flag, teste all signified -- their names are not very revealing.

As in several places you need to know the first and the last node of a linked list, it would be good to create a linkedlist structure that has both these pointers (first/last) together with functions to manipulate such a linked list (add a node to it, extract a node from it, concatenate two lists, display a list, ...etc). This will help to take abstraction of tedious manipulations and make the code more readable.

I would implement quick sort like this: choose the value of the first node as pivot value (as you did), then visit all nodes in the input linked list and decide whether to move them to the end of a left list, a mid list or a right list. The mid list would contain the node(s) that have the pivot value. Make sure that the caller gets an access to these three new linked lists. As each  node is moved from the input list into one of these three lists, the input list will be empty at the end of the partitioning. The caller can then decide what to do with these three lists: apply a recursive sort on the left list, the right list and then concatenate the results.


Here is how I would suggest implementing it:
The element (Node)
struct element {
    int key[2];
    struct element *next;
};

struct element *create_element(int key, int payload) {
    struct element *el = malloc(sizeof *el);
    el->key[0] = key;
    el->key[1] = payload;
    el->next = NULL;
    return el;
}

void display_element(struct element *el) {
   printf("%d(%d)", el->key[0], el->key[1]);
}

The linked list
struct linkedlist {
    struct element *first;
    struct element *last;
};

struct linkedlist *create_linkedlist() {
    struct linkedlist *list = malloc(sizeof(*list));
    list->first = list->last = NULL;
    return list;
}

void linkedlist_append(struct linkedlist *list, struct element *el) {
    if (!list->first) {
        list->first = el;
    } else {
        list->last->next = el;
    }
    list->last = el;
    el->next = NULL;
}

void linkedlist_extend(struct linkedlist *list, struct linkedlist *other) {
    if (!other->first) {
        return; 
    }
    if (!list->first) {
        list->first = other->first;
    } else {
        list->last->next = other->first;
    }
    list->last = other->last;
    other->first = other->last = NULL;
}

struct element *linkedlist_extract_first(struct linkedlist *list) {
    if (!list->first) {
        return NULL;
    }
    struct element* el = list->first;
    list->first = el->next;
    if (!list->first) {
        list->last = NULL;
    }
    el->next = NULL;
    return el;
}

void linkedlist_display(struct linkedlist *list) {
    struct element *el = list->first;
    while (el) {
        display_element(el);
        printf(" -> ");
        el = el->next;
    }
    printf("null");
}

Quicksort:
With the above functions in place, the code specific to quick sort becomes almost trivial:
void partition(struct linkedlist *list, struct linkedlist *left,
               struct linkedlist *mid, struct linkedlist *right) {
    // Guaranteed that list is not empty
    struct element *el = linkedlist_extract_first(list); 
    int pivotKey = el->key[0];
    while (el) 
        // Decide where to move this element to:
        struct linkedlist *target = el->key[0] < pivotKey ? left
                                  : el->key[0] > pivotKey ? right
                                  : mid;
        linkedlist_append(target, el); // Move it
        el = linkedlist_extract_first(list); // Take next
    }
}

void quick_sort(struct linkedlist *list) {
    if (list->first == list->last) { // Empty or one element only
        return; // Nothing to do
    }
    struct linkedlist *left = create_linkedlist();
    struct linkedlist *mid = create_linkedlist();
    struct linkedlist *right = create_linkedlist();
    partition(list, left, mid, right); // Will populate left, mid, right
    // At this point list is empty
    quick_sort(left);
    quick_sort(right);
    // Concatenate the sorted partitions
    linkedlist_extend(list, left);
    linkedlist_extend(list, mid);
    linkedlist_extend(list, right);
}

Example run
int main() {
    struct linkedlist *list = create_linkedlist();
    linkedlist_append(list, create_element(30, 0));
    linkedlist_append(list, create_element(50, 0));
    linkedlist_append(list, create_element(40, 0));
    linkedlist_append(list, create_element(10, 0));
    linkedlist_append(list, create_element( 5, 0));
    linkedlist_append(list, create_element(20, 0));
    printf("Input:\n");
    linkedlist_display(list);
    quick_sort(list);
    printf("Sorted:\n");
    linkedlist_display(list);
    return 0;
}

The output will be:
Input:
30(0) -> 50(0) -> 40(0) -> 10(0) -> 5(0) -> 20(0) -> null
Sorted:
5(0) -> 10(0) -> 20(0) -> 30(0) -> 40(0) -> 50(0) -> null 

Final remarks
Quick sort is not an ideal candidate algorithm for linked lists. Mergesort is a better choice.
Taking the first node as pivot will lead to a worst case time complexity when the input list is already sorted with distinct values (because then left will remain empty, and right will have only one element less). But taking another pivot node would mean more work, as you can only traverse elements from left to right -- there is no random access.
Addendum: Without struct linkedlist
As you mention in comments you are not allowed to create another struct, I provide here the code that uses the two members of this struct as separate variables and parameters. It makes the code less readable in my opinion. I don't understand the educational value in such restrictions, but here you are:
Linked list functions
void linkedlist_append(struct element **listFirstPtr, struct element **listLastPtr,
                       struct element *el) {
    if (!*listFirstPtr) {
        *listFirstPtr = el;
    } else {
        (*listLastPtr)->next = el;
    }
    *listLastPtr = el;
    el->next = NULL;
}

void linkedlist_extend(struct element **listFirstPtr, struct element **listLastPtr,
                       struct element *otherFirst, struct element *otherLast) {
    if (!otherFirst) {
        return; 
    }
    if (!*listFirstPtr) {
        *listFirstPtr = otherFirst;
    } else {
        (*listLastPtr)->next = otherFirst;
    }
    *listLastPtr = otherLast;
}

struct element *linkedlist_extract_first(struct element **listFirstPtr,
                                         struct element **listLastPtr) {
    if (!*listFirstPtr) {
        return NULL;
    }
    struct element* el = *listFirstPtr;
    *listFirstPtr = el->next;
    if (!*listFirstPtr) {
        listLastPtr = NULL;
    }
    el->next = NULL;
    return el;
}

void linkedlist_display(struct element *listFirst) {
    struct element *el = listFirst;
    while (el) {
        display_element(el);
        printf(" -> ");
        el = el->next;
    }
    printf("null");
}

Quicksort
void partition(struct element **listFirstPtr, struct element **listLastPtr, 
               struct element **leftFirstPtr, struct element **leftLastPtr,
               struct element **midFirstPtr, struct element **midLastPtr,
               struct element **rightFirstPtr, struct element **rightLastPtr) {
    // Guaranteed that list is not empty
    struct element *el = linkedlist_extract_first(listFirstPtr, listLastPtr); 
    int pivotKey = el->key[0];
    while (el) {
        if (el->key[0] < pivotKey) {
            linkedlist_append(leftFirstPtr, leftLastPtr, el);
        } else if (el->key[0] > pivotKey) {
            linkedlist_append(rightFirstPtr, rightLastPtr, el);
        } else {
            linkedlist_append(midFirstPtr, midLastPtr, el);
        }
        el = linkedlist_extract_first(listFirstPtr, listLastPtr);
    }
}

void quick_sort(struct element **listFirstPtr, struct element **listLastPtr) {
    if (*listFirstPtr == *listLastPtr) {
        return;
    }
    struct element *leftFirst = NULL, *leftLast = NULL;
    struct element *midFirst = NULL, *midLast = NULL;
    struct element *rightFirst = NULL, *rightLast = NULL;
    partition(listFirstPtr, listLastPtr, &leftFirst, &leftLast, 
              &midFirst, &midLast, &rightFirst, &rightLast);
    // At this point list is empty
    quick_sort(&leftFirst, &leftLast);
    quick_sort(&rightFirst, &rightLast);
    // Concatenate the sorted partitions
    linkedlist_extend(listFirstPtr, listLastPtr, leftFirst, leftLast);
    linkedlist_extend(listFirstPtr, listLastPtr, midFirst, midLast);
    linkedlist_extend(listFirstPtr, listLastPtr, rightFirst, rightLast);
}

Example run
int main() {
    struct element *listFirst = NULL, *listLast = NULL;
    linkedlist_append(&listFirst, &listLast, create_element(30, 0));
    linkedlist_append(&listFirst, &listLast, create_element(50, 0));
    linkedlist_append(&listFirst, &listLast, create_element(40, 0));
    linkedlist_append(&listFirst, &listLast, create_element(10, 0));
    linkedlist_append(&listFirst, &listLast, create_element( 5, 0));
    linkedlist_append(&listFirst, &listLast, create_element(20, 0));
    printf("Input:\n");
    linkedlist_display(listFirst);
    quick_sort(&listFirst, &listLast);
    printf("\nSorted:\n");
    linkedlist_display(listFirst);
    return 0;
}


In my exercise, I can only have the struct element structure. I cannot create a struct linkedlist. But I liked the way you solved it, it was brilliant. Is there a way to perform this sorting by dividing the list into two parts and then merging the two parts, without creating an additional struct?

Sure, the struct linkedlist is a pair of two pointers, so you can work with those individually, and pass pointer-pointers when they need to be updated by the function.

Added a version to my answer without using extra struct.
